# Failed attempt of Linear Regression implementation in Octave for multiple features

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, octave, gradient-descent

I have implemented the Machine Learning Course Week 2 Programming Assignment (multiple features part) to  another database "House Sales in King County, USA" from Kaggle. Also I have modified database and decreased the number of features.

So my problem is when I try to calculate a price to check solution, code gives me a very different price with calculated thetas than expected.

I have not completed the course yet (now starting to week 6) and I am not able to come with a solution. But I want to try my own implementation however I did not share this in Course Discussion Forum because this code includes answers to programming assignment.

In conclusion, your valuable advises will highly appreciated.

These are my codes:

```
clear ; close all; clc

fprintf('Loading data ...\n');

%% Load Data
data = load('multidata.txt');
X = data(:, 1:8);
y = data(:, 9);
m = length(y);

fprintf('Program paused. Press enter to continue.\n');
pause;

% Print out some data points. x ve y değerlerini görüyoruz. 
fprintf('First 10 examples from the dataset: \n');
fprintf(' x = [%.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f], y = %.0f \n', [X(1:10,:) y(1:10,:)]');

fprintf('Program paused. Press enter to continue.\n');
pause;

% Scale features and set them to zero mean. 
fprintf('Normalizing Features ...\n');

%FeatureNormalization için tanımlanan fonksiyonu çalıştırıyor. 
[X mu sigma] = featureNormalize(X);

%Normalizasyon sonrası dataları görüyoruz. 
fprintf('First 10 examples from the dataset: \n');
fprintf(' x = [%.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f], y = %.0f \n', [X(1:10,:) y(1:10,:)]');

fprintf('Program paused. Press enter to continue.\n');
pause;

% Add intercept term to X (1 değerinde x0 feature'ı ekleniyor)
X = [ones(m, 1) X];
%Normalizasyon sonrası eklemenin ilk 10 numune için görüntüsü
fprintf('First 10 examples from the dataset: \n');
fprintf(' x = [%.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f] \n', [X(1:10,:)]');

fprintf('Program paused. Press enter to continue.\n');
pause;

%% ================ Part 2: Gradient Descent ================
fprintf('Running gradient descent ...\n');

% Choose some alpha value
alpha = 0.001; %alpha 0.001, 0.003, 0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 0.3, 1 
num_iters = 5000;

% Init Theta and Run Gradient Descent 
theta = zeros(9, 1);
[theta, J_history] = gradientDescentMulti(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters);

% Plot the convergence graph
figure;
plot(1:numel(J_history), J_history, '-b', 'LineWidth', 2);
xlabel('Number of iterations');
ylabel('Cost J');

% Display gradient descent's result
fprintf('Theta computed from gradient descent: \n');
fprintf(' %f \n', theta);
fprintf('\n');

% Estimate the price of a house
price =  [1,3,2.5,3400,16603,3,10,3400,0]*theta; 
% ============================================================

fprintf(['Predicted price of a house ' ...
     '(using gradient descent):\n $%f\n'], price);

fprintf('Program paused. Press enter to continue.\n');
pause;
```

This code is for Feature Normalization:

```
function [X_norm, mu, sigma] = featureNormalize(X)
X_norm = X;
mu = zeros(1, size(X, 8));
sigma = zeros(1, size(X, 8));

mu = mean(X);
sigma  = std(X);
X_norm = (X-mu)./sigma;

end
```

This code is for Gradient Desent

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescentMulti(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)

% Initialize some useful values
m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

for iter = 1:num_iters

error = (X * theta) - y;
theta = theta - ((alpha/m) * (X' * error));

% Save the cost J in every iteration    
J_history(iter) = computeCostMulti(X, y, theta);

end

end
```

This code is for Cost Compute:

```
function J = computeCostMulti(X, y, theta)

% Initialize some useful values
m = length(y); % number of training examples

% You need to return the following variables correctly 
J = 0;

J =(1/(2*m))*(sum(((X*theta)-y).^2));
end
```

This the Output of the Program:

```
Loading data ...
Program paused. Press enter to continue.
First 10 examples from the dataset:
x = [3 1 1180 5650 3 7 1180 0], y = 221900
x = [3 2 2570 7242 3 7 2170 400], y = 538000
x = [2 1 770 10000 3 6 770 0], y = 180000
x = [4 3 1960 5000 5 7 1050 910], y = 604000
x = [3 2 1680 8080 3 8 1680 0], y = 510000
x = [4 4 5420 101930 3 11 3890 1530], y = 1225000
x = [3 2 1715 6819 3 7 1715 0], y = 257500
x = [3 2 1060 9711 3 7 1060 0], y = 291850
x = [3 1 1780 7470 3 7 1050 730], y = 229500
x = [3 2 1890 6560 3 7 1890 0], y = 323000
Program paused. Press enter to continue.
Normalizing Features ...
First 10 examples from the dataset:
x = [-0 -1 -1 -0 -1 -1 -1 -1], y = 221900
x = [-0 0 1 -0 -1 -1 0 0], y = 538000
x = [-1 -1 -1 -0 -1 -1 -1 -1], y = 180000
x = [1 1 -0 -0 2 -1 -1 1], y = 604000
x = [-0 -0 -0 -0 -1 0 -0 -1], y = 510000
x = [1 3 4 2 -1 3 3 3], y = 1225000
x = [-0 0 -0 -0 -1 -1 -0 -1], y = 257500
x = [-0 -1 -1 -0 -1 -1 -1 -1], y = 291850
x = [-0 -1 -0 -0 -1 -1 -1 1], y = 229500
x = [-0 1 -0 -0 -1 -1 0 -1], y = 323000
Program paused. Press enter to continue.
First 10 examples from the dataset:
x = [1 -0 -1 -1 -0 -1 -1 -1 -1]
x = [1 -0 0 1 -0 -1 -1 0 0]
x = [1 -1 -1 -1 -0 -1 -1 -1 -1]
x = [1 1 1 -0 -0 2 -1 -1 1]
x = [1 -0 -0 -0 -0 -1 0 -0 -1]
x = [1 1 3 4 2 -1 3 3 3]
x = [1 -0 0 -0 -0 -1 -1 -0 -1]
x = [1 -0 -1 -1 -0 -1 -1 -1 -1]
x = [1 -0 -1 -0 -0 -1 -1 -1 1]
x = [1 -0 1 -0 -0 -1 -1 0 -1]
Program paused. Press enter to continue.
Running gradient descent ...
Theta computed from gradient descent:
536458.148898
-39768.741950
1127.113170
96860.285036
-9795.554225
37968.073474
122038.218945
73282.058139
63890.263077

Predicted price of a house (using gradient descent):
$417602636.107368
Program paused. Press enter to continue.
>>
```

Answer (score 0):

[You're missing the big summation here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6QBJ.png)
and the multiplication X' * error actually should be element wise like: error .* X.

So in a nutshell your theta should be something like
 `theta = theta - ((alpha/m) * sum((error .* X)));`

Please check for the sizes of the matrix if anything goes wrong, but basically that's the most immediate error that i can see, hope i helped and recheck the explanation for the formula, once you get it you won't even need to look after it!